# Select from unknown table name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How i can got online from different tables ?

```
SELECT count(online) FROM (SELECT UserTableName FROM `name`) WHERE online = 1


--------------
UserTableName
--------------
users_1
users_2
users_3

--------------
users_x
--------------
1
0
0
1
```

I need get online and table names from tables different tables example:

```
-----------------
 online | table
-----------------
       5| users_1
       3| users_2
       9| users_3
```

Comment: The name of the table would only be unknown if the schema was poorly designed

Comment: You have 1 table per user and an unknown number of users?

Comment: Why do you think to need one table per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 1 table per user then you can create a sql statement programatically (grabbing the distinct table names from your linking table and unioning them all) and then submitting. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

for example given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,username from users where id < 3;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | John     |
|  2 | Jane     |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from john;
+--------+
| online |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      0 |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from jane;
+--------+
| online |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      1 |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This code

```
SET @SQL =
( 
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(GCSTRING)
FROM
(
SELECT 'A' AS GC,CONCAT(sstring,name,fstring, usertable,ustring) gcstring
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT 'select count(*) as online # ' as sstring, concat(char(39),username,char(39)) as name, 
' as user from ' as fstring, username AS usertable, ' Where online = 1  UNION '  as USTRING from users where id < 3
) S
) T
GROUP BY GC
)
;

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,',',' ');
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'#',',');
SET @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL,1,LENGTH(@SQL) - 6);
SET @SQL = CONCAT(@SQL,';');
#SELECT @SQL;

prepare stmt1 from @sql;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

Produces this result

```
+--------+------+
| online | user |
+--------+------+
|      1 | John |
|      2 | Jane |
+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```